# How to select value from dropdown based on labels using Selenium Web driver(IE11)-Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select value from Excess dropdown based on the type and cover.Id for all the Excess dropdown is same which is cboAmount

For example  :::
1 )i might need to select 200 from dropdopwn for cover building and Type Core
2) i might need to select 1000 from dropdopwn for cover contents and Type imposed

Please find attached SCreenshot of application and a partial xml.

I have tried below but its not working

```
WebElement bldCoreExcessWE = GlobalVar.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//font[text()='Building']/following::font[text()='Core']/following::select[@id='cboAmount']"));
Select selIE1 = new Select(bldCoreExcessWE);
selIE1.selectByVisibleText(BuildCore);
```

Screenshot ::[PageAmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzDqF.png)

XML:

```
<TABLE ID="tblExcess" Width="100%" Cols="3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<TR>

</TR>
<TR Height="">
<TD Colspan="3">
<TR Height="">
<TD Class="SRE" Width="33%">
<font class="flabel10pt">Buildings</font>
<input type="hidden" name="N/Root/ACORD/BoringSvcRs/un_uk_com.bbc_RomeFetchResultsRs/RomeLineBoring/Dwell[com.bbc_ItemIdInfo/OtherIdentifier[./OtherIdTypeCd='CompId']/OtherId != ''][1][Coverage/Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc[1] and Coverage/un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Coverage[Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !='' and un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Deductible[un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !=''][1]/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc[../un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDispTypeCd='E']" size="" CallFunction="" value="BULD" ID="hidExcessCoverCd" onFocus="HighlightScript(this);" onBlur="ResetScript(this);" />
<input type="hidden" name="N/Root/ACORD/BoringSvcRs/un_uk_com.bbc_RomeFetchResultsRs/RomeLineBoring/Dwell[com.bbc_ItemIdInfo/OtherIdentifier[./OtherIdTypeCd='CompId']/OtherId != ''][1][Coverage/Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc[1] and Coverage/un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Coverage[Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !='' and un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Deductible[un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !=''][1]/ItemIdInfo[../un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDispTypeCd='E']/OtherIdentifier[OtherIdTypeCd ='S3Checksum']/OtherId" size="" CallFunction="" value="0" ID="hidExcessChecksum" onFocus="HighlightScript(this);" onBlur="ResetScript(this);" />
<input type="hidden" name="N/Root/ACORD/BoringSvcRs/un_uk_com.bbc_RomeFetchResultsRs/RomeLineBoring/Dwell[com.bbc_ItemIdInfo/OtherIdentifier[./OtherIdTypeCd='CompId']/OtherId != ''][1][Coverage/Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc[1] and Coverage/un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Coverage[Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !='' and un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Deductible[un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !=''][1]/ItemIdInfo[../un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDispTypeCd='E']/OtherIdentifier[OtherIdTypeCd='S3DwellUnitNbr']/OtherId" size="" CallFunction="" value="+1" ID="hidExcessDwellNo" onFocus="HighlightScript(this);" onBlur="ResetScript(this);" />
<input type="hidden" name="N/Root/ACORD/BoringSvcRs/un_uk_com.bbc_RomeFetchResultsRs/RomeLineBoring/Dwell[com.bbc_ItemIdInfo/OtherIdentifier[./OtherIdTypeCd='CompId']/OtherId != ''][1][Coverage/Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc[1] and Coverage/un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Coverage[Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !='' and un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Deductible[un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !=''][1]/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleTypeDesc[../un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDispTypeCd='E']" size="" CallFunction="" value="Core" ID="hidCoverType" onFocus="HighlightScript(this);" onBlur="ResetScript(this);" />
</TD>
<TD Class="SRE" Width="33%">
<font class="flabel10pt">Core</font>
</TD>
<TD Class="SRE" Width="34%" VAlign="Top">
<FONT CLASS="flabel"> </FONT>
<font class="fLabel"></font>
<select name="/Root/ACORD/BoringSvcRs/un_uk_com.bbc_RomeFetchResultsRs/RomeLineBoring/Dwell[com.bbc_ItemIdInfo/OtherIdentifier[./OtherIdTypeCd='CompId']/OtherId != ''][1][Coverage/Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc[1] and Coverage/un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Coverage[Deductible/un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !='' and un_uk_com.bbc_ContainerType = 'CHK'][1]/Deductible[un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDesc !=''][1]/FormatCurrencyAmt[../un_uk_com.bbc_DeductibleDispTypeCd='E']/Amt" id="cboAmount" Title="" class="flabel10pt" onFocus="HighlightScript(this);" onBlur="ResetScript(this);return true;">
<OPTION value="-1">[Select]</OPTION><OPTION value="0">0         </OPTION><OPTION value="50">50        </OPTION><OPTION value="75">75        </OPTION><OPTION value="100" selected="true">100       </OPTION><OPTION value="200">200       </OPTION><OPTION value="300">300       </OPTION><OPTION value="400">400       </OPTION><OPTION value="500">500       </OPTION><OPTION value="1000">1000      </OPTION>
</select>
```

Comment: @Guy .tried as u suggested.Now getting below error at select.selectByValue(BuildCore) Step     ::Cannot click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function returned an unexpected error, but no error could be returned from Internet Explorer's JavaScript engine. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: mY fault.Thanks Guy for your help.It is working fine as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class for this. In addition, it should be `Buildings` in your `xpath`, not `Building`

```
WebElement bldCoreExcessWE = GlobalVar.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//font[contains(text(), 'Buildings')]/following::font[contains(text(), 'Core')]/following::select[@id='cboAmount']"));

Select select = new Select(bldCoreExcessWE);
select.selectByValue(BuildCore);
// or
select.selectByVisibleText(BuildCore);
```

Comment: I need to select value from Excess dropdown based on the type and cover.cboAmount is same for  all the Excess dropdown.please see screenshot to undestand the problem

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey The `xpath` in your question works for you? if so use it instead of `By.id("cboAmount")`. I edited my answer.

Comment: No it does not work as mentioned.I raised question here for same

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey I edited my answer, try to use `contains` in the `xpath` and change `Building` to `Buildings`

Comment: Tried the same but no luck.. do u think the code ,i have written to find web element is correct?. i am doubting on that

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey The `xpath` looks ok. Try to use `contains` like in my answer and to select by value (also in my answer)

Comment: Working fine..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try like below

```
// as you said ID for each Excess Drop down is same 
// so first take them inside list firts 
// like belwo 

List<WebElement> excessColumn = driver.findElements(By.id("cboAmount"));
// excessColumn will have an index value (like for column one index =0,
column 2 index =1 and so on )that you can use like below

// now on the basis of Cover and Types

    String Covers= "Buildings";
    String Type = "Core";
    if(Covers.equals("Buildings") && Type.equals("Core")){
        // now select data on the basis of index 
        excessColumn.get(0).sendKeys("100"); // for column first (EXCESSS)
       // or you can also use technique that you use for dd selection
    }else if(Covers.equals("Contents") && Type.equals("Imposed")){
        // for 4rd excess column
        excessColumn.get(3).sendKeys("200");
    }
```

Comment: I need to add one thing here. Thanks for the answer .Basically covers are not fixed (might increase or decrease)so the indexing of Excess Amount might gets changed.Thats why i need to select Building and Core Excees Amount if three is building and core label before dropdown.I will update my question

Comment: yeah sure but for now above will work when data increase we have to update above solution little bit as basic concept will remain same always and also if u think above helped you than please mark it as your answer thanks @ Devkant Krishnatrey